# SwiftUI dismiss modal sheet presented from NavigationView (Xcode Beta 5)

Tags: swiftui

I am attempting to dismiss a modal view presented via a `.sheet` in SwiftUI - called by a `Button` which is within a `NavigationView`s `navigationBarItems`, as per below:

```
struct ModalView : View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode  

    var body: some View {       
        Button(action: {
            self.presentationMode.value.dismiss()
        }, label: { Text("Save")})
    }   

}

struct ContentView : View {

    @State var showModal: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
         NavigationView { 
           Text("test")
           .navigationBarTitle(Text("Navigation Title Text"))
           .navigationBarItems(trailing:
               Button(action: {
                   self.showModal = true
               }, label: { Text("Add") })
                   .sheet(isPresented: $showModal, content: { ModalView() })
           )
        }
    }

}
```

The modal does not dismiss when the Save button is tapped, it just remains on screen. The only way to get rid of it is swiping down on the modal.

Printing the value of `self.presentationMode.value` always shows `false` so it seems to think that it hasn't been presented.

This only happens when it is presented from the `NavigationView`. Take that out and it works fine.

Am I missing something here, or is this a beta issue?

Comment: When I tried something similar a couple of betas ago it presented once. I don't think that you need to worry about showModal, it is reset by the sheet()

Comment: Just realised I missed a critical sentence in the question - the modal displays fine, but does not dismiss!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to move the `.sheet` outside the Button.

```
NavigationView {
  Text("test")
  .navigationBarTitle(Text("Navigation Title Text"))
  .navigationBarItems(trailing:
     Button("Add") {
       self.showModal = true
     }
  )
  .sheet(isPresented: $showModal, content: { ModalView() })
}
```

You can even move it outside the `NavigationView` closure.

```
NavigationView {
  Text("test")
  .navigationBarTitle(Text("Navigation Title Text"))
  .navigationBarItems(trailing:
     Button("Add") { self.showModal = true }
  )
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showModal, content: { ModalView() })
```

Notice you can also simplify the Button call if you have a simple text button.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that I didn't try that. Thanks so much! Can you explain why it wasn't working when it was within the button? Still a bit unclear about that.

Comment: It could be a bug that, for some reason, is causing the Button inside the navigation bar to be treated differently than if it was inside the view.Or, maybe the navigationBar is placed outside the NavigationView, being its sibling. I can't think of any other reason right now.

Comment: excellent workaround, but I guess it's also a bug must be handled by Apple

Comment: Very helpful! Just FYI, as of April 2023,`.navigationBarItems(trailing:` syntax is deprecated in favor of `.toolbar {ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {` . See [https://stackoverflow.com/q/65268312/1359088](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65268312/1359088).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not readily apparent in the documentation and most tutorials opt for simple solutions. But I really wanted a button in the NavigationBar of the sheet that would dismiss the sheet. Here is the solution in six steps:

1. Set the DetailView to not show.
2. Add a button to set the DetailView to show.
3. Call the .sheet(isPresented modifier to display the sheet.
4. Wrap the view that will appear in the sheet in a NavigationView because we want to display a .navigationBarItem button.
5. PresentationMode is required to dismiss the sheet view.
6. Add a button to the NavBar and call the dismiss method.

import SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // 1
    @State private var showingDetail = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            Button("Show Detail") {
                showingDetail = true // 2
            }
            // 3
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
                // 4
                NavigationView {
                    DetailView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct DetailView: View {
    // 5
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View!")
            // 6
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "x.circle")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            })
    }
}
```