# SwiftUI - Add Menu to navigationBarTrailing's ToolbarItem

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `NavigationVeiw` that has a `ToolbarItem` on the trailing side of its navigation-bar.

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Text("Button")
        })
    }
}
```

`navigationBarItems(leading:trailing:)`is deprecated. Therefore, I am using `toolbar(content:)` with `navigationBarTrailing` placement. [- Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbaritems(leading:trailing:))

---

I have used contextMenu on the Button.

```
   .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
            .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                Text("Menu Item 1")
                Text("Menu Item 2")
                Text("Menu Item 3")
            })
        }
    }
```

It's not sensitive. You have to press hard to present it. I need to present it with a single touch like iOS Photo App's Add button. It is presented with a single touch.

How to show Menu with a single touch (not press)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.contextMenu` is a 3D Touch (press and hold) just use a regular `Menu`

```
.toolbar {
     ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
         Menu(content: {
             Text("Menu Item 1")
             Text("Menu Item 2")
              Text("Menu Item 3")
         }, label: {Text("button")})
      }
  }
```

Comment: But with the label `Image(systemName: "plus")` the button is very hard to tap ! How to solve this issue?

Comment: You have to stretch the tappable area by one of these methods `.frame( maxWidth: .infinity,  maxHeight: .infinity)` or `.contentShape(Rectangle())` put it right on the `Image`

Comment: I tried it but does not work :( I even tried to use `.padding()` but the problem is that it obviously shifts to the left and it does not look good

Comment: Ask a question with a  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Okay, I started a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68613132/toolbaritem-with-a-menu-very-hard-to-tap-swiftui